# How to use a RegExp literal as object key?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use create a object that contains regular expressions as the key value. I tried to use the following syntax:

```
var kv = {
    /key/g : "value"
};
```

But it fails according [JavaScript lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/):

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id
```

How can I fix it?

#### Update

Background: The reason why I want to do this is to implement a workaround that fixes wrong unicode in a HTTP API result. I know this is very hackish, but since I have no control over the API server code I think this is the best I can do.

Currently I implemented the mapping by having a keys array and a values array:

```
function fixUnicode(text) {

    var result = text;
    var keys = [];
    var values = [];
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&copy;/g); values.push("&eacute;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&uml;/g); values.push("&egrave;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&ordf;/g); values.push("&ecirc;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&laquo;/g); values.push("&euml;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&nbsp;/g); values.push("&agrave;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&curren;/g); values.push("&auml;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&cent;/g); values.push("&acirc;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&sup1;/g); values.push("&ugrave;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&raquo;/g); values.push("&ucirc;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&frac14;/g); values.push("&uuml;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&acute;/g); values.push("&ocirc;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&para;/g); values.push("&ouml;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&reg;/g); values.push("&icirc;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&macr;/g); values.push("&iuml;");
    keys.push(/&Atilde;&sect;/g); values.push("&ccedil;");

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
        result = result.replace(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I want to implement to use a JavaScript object to map keys as values:

```
function fixUnicode(text) {

    var result = text;
    var keys = {
        /&Atilde;&copy;/g : "&eacute;",
        /&Atilde;&uml;/g :  "&egrave;"
        // etc...
    };

    for (var key in keys) {
        result = result.replace(key, keys[key]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is that even possible? I know you can create a alue with a regex string, but I've never heard of using regex for a key.

Comment: What's the use case, why not have it `var kv = [{rx: 'key1', modifier: 'g', value:'value1'}, {rx: 'key2', flags: 'g', value:'value2'}]`, then loop over the array and build the regex with `var rx = new RegExp(kv[0].rx, kv[0].modifier);`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This can be done, but not using object literal syntax.  You'll need to do it like this:

```
var kv = {};
kv[/key/g] = "value";
console.log(kv[/key/g]); // "value"
```

---

Edit: this could probably use some explaining.  As xanatos commented below, what's really happening here is that the key, `/key/g` in this case, is being `toString()`'d to create the key.  This is important to know, because it has an effect on key uniqueness.  Consider the following:

```
var x = {},
    reg = /foo/;

x[reg] = 'bar';
console.log(x[reg]); // "bar"
console.log(x[reg.toString()]); // "bar"
console.log(x['/foo/']); // "bar'
```

In summary, I'm semi-scared to ask *why* you need to do this, but assuming you have your reasons, be careful and make sure you understand *what* is really happening :)

---

Edit 2: So in response to your updated question, you should be able to achieve something pretty close to what you want.  You can use the object literal syntax as long as you wrap the regular expression in quotes.  Unfortunately that means you'll have to manually reconstruct an actually RegExp object out of that key though.  For example:

```
var result = "abcdef",
    replacements = {
        "/a/g": "FOO",
        "/d/i": "BAR"
    };

for (var key in replacements) {
    var parts = key.split('/');
    result = result.replace(new RegExp(parts[1], parts[2]), replacements[key]);
}

console.log(result); //FOObcBARef
```

---

Edit 3: Because, why not.  I was so stuck on making your object-literal syntax work, that I didn't consider the fact that you never need to actually look up the replacement by the pattern itself (i.e., there's no need for object keys at all).  Here's a more efficient approach using arrays that doesn't require the RegExp reconstruction:

```
var result = "abcdef",
    replacements = [
        [/a/g, "FOO"],
        [/d/i, "BAR"]
    ];

for (var i = 0, len = replacements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var replacement = replacements[i];
    result = result.replace(replacement[0], replacement[1]);
}

console.log(result); //FOObcBARef
```

---

Edit 4: Because I'm bored and I like this question.  Here's the ninja version:

```
var result = "abcdef",
    replacements = [
        [/a/g, "FOO"],
        [/d/i, "BAR"]
    ], r;

while ((r = replacements.shift()) && (result = String.prototype.replace.apply(result, r))) {}

console.log(result); //FOObcBARef
```

Comment: This in the end will make the rx a string. It's like doing `kv[(/key/g).toString()] = "value"`

Comment: Good point (+1) - I've expanded my answer to include an explanation.

Comment: Great insight on using a straight array. You questioned the use case, but I found a great use for this to specify rules in a lexer that I'm writing. The first element in the array is the regex to match, and the second element is the token value for that pattern.

Comment: How about when replacements are not literals and should include matching groups?

Comment: @ccpizza can you show an example of what you mean? Any of the solutions above should still work with regular replacement syntax (e.g., `"$1, $2, $3"`).

Answer (score 16):

I think this question deserves an updated answer. Since ES6, a new type (standard built-in object) called Map was created to cover cases like this one among others.

A Map is very similar to an Object, except it allows any type as key.

Map.prototype.forEach() can then be used to loop over each key/value pair.

In your case, your function could now be:

```
function fixUnicode(text) {

    var result = text;
    var replaceMap = new Map();
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&copy;/g, "&eacute;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&uml;/g, "&egrave;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&ordf;/g, "&ecirc;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&laquo;/g, "&euml;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&nbsp;/g, "&agrave;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&curren;/g, "&auml;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&cent;/g, "&acirc;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&sup1;/g, "&ugrave;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&raquo;/g, "&ucirc;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&frac14;/g, "&uuml;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&acute;/g, "&ocirc;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&para;/g, "&ouml;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&reg;/g, "&icirc;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&macr;/g, "&iuml;");
    replaceMap.set(/&Atilde;&sect;/g, "&ccedil;");

    replaceMap.forEach(function (newString, old) {
      result = result.replace(old, newString);
    });

    return result;
}
```

You can read more about maps at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)

Comment: Neat ! Very useful to transform String URLs in character encoded ones.

Answer (score 3):

Object keys cannot be RegExp objects. You must use a string or a valid ID. That being said, you could do something like this:

```
var kv = {
    "/key/g": "value"
};
```

I'm curious. Why do you want to do this?

**EDIT:** I am partially mistaken. RegExp objects can be used as keys, but not using the object literal syntax. See jmar777's answer.

Comment: RegExp's cannot be be used, anything that is not a string will be converted to a string before it becomes a key in a hash map. Therefore, what really happens is what you suggested (a string version of the regexp is used).  `var o = {}; o[/key/g] = "value"; for (var prop in o) {console.log(prop instance of RegExp)} // yields false`. Having said that, the toString() of the RegExp may be good enough for OP

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an expression as a key by wrapping it in `[]` when creating an object:

```
var kv = {
    [/key/g] : "value"
};
```

Comment: However, the key is still a string. Not a regex object/literal.

Answer (score 0):

Although this topic is old, it might be useful for reference to add another option.

While have regular expressions are not allowed as object property, they would be fine as a value.

**Options**

- RegEx strings as object property and then convert back with `new RegExp()` *(as mentioned previously)*
  Consideration: have to run an extra constructor function & double escape special characters e.g. `\\s+`
- Pairs of RegEx, replacement in arrays *(as mentioned previously)*
- Swap property & value in the object i.e. replacement property and RegEx value

```js
let str = 'Change this key and THIS KEY.';
const obj = {
  'value': /key/gi,
  'that': /this/gi
};
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => str = str.replace(value, key));
console.log(str);
// Change that value and that value.
```

**Note:**

- Arrow function was added in ECMAScript 2015 aka ES6
- `Object.entries()` was added in ECMAScript 2017 aka ES8
- `Object.keys()` or `for` loop can be used for older browsers