# regexp inside javascript mapobject

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to edit javascript from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21198129/2250595)
and use regexp inside map, if possible: like string starts with "xyz", but that syntax is not working for me :

```
var anchorMap = {
    "A": "/products/A",
    "B": "/products/B",
    /^xyz: "/products/xyz"
}
```

is that possible ? Or what is the easiest way to implement such logic ?

Comment: I'm sure this will help you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365027/how-to-use-a-regexp-literal-as-object-key

Answer (score 0):

That's not something I would recommend (and I don't really understand your goal here - however, you could make the regex a string and loop the keys to test against.

```js
var anchorMap = {
    "A": "/products/A",
    "B": "/products/B",
    "^.{3}": "/products/xyz"
};

const k = Object.keys(anchorMap).find(e => new RegExp(e).test("xyz"));
console.log(anchorMap[k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define keys as regex and than using find you can see which regex key it is matching and get the value for that particular key from object.

```js
var anchorMap = {
    "A": "/products/A",
    "B": "/products/B",
    [`^xyz`]: "/products/xyz"
}

let str = 'xyz'

let op = Object.keys(anchorMap).find( e => new RegExp(e).test(str))

console.log(anchorMap[op])
```